# Python Pandas: How do I return members of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I´m doing some resarch on a dataframe for people that are relative. But I can´t manage when I find brothers, I can´t find a way to write them down all on a specific column. Here follow an example:

```
cols = ['Name','Father','Brother']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Brother':'',
                   'Father':['Erick Moon','Ralph Docker','Erick Moon','Stewart Adborn'],
                    'Name':['John Smith','Rodolph Ruppert','Mathew Common',"Patrick French"]                   
                  },columns=cols)

df
          Name          Father           Brother
0       John Smith    Erick Moon        
1  Rodolph Ruppert    Ralph Docker        
2    Mathew Common    Erick Moon        
3   Patrick French    Stewart Adborn
```

What I want is this:

```
          Name          Father           Brother
0       John Smith    Erick Moon       Mathew Common    
1  Rodolph Ruppert    Ralph Docker        
2    Mathew Common    Erick Moon       John Smith 
3   Patrick French    Stewart Adborn
```

I apreciate any help!

Comment: Does this dataset only include males? Can there be more than 2 brothers?

Comment: this mays be useful: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html

Comment: No. I just made a pseudo code. There are women too. Also, it´s possible more than two brothers. I´look into reshaping. I tried groupby, but I couldn´t manage to get only other brother because it would rewrite twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea you can try, firstly create a `Brother` column with all brothers as a list including itself and then remove itself separately. The code could probably be optimized but where you can start from:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df['Brother'] = df.groupby('Father')['Name'].transform(lambda g: [g.values])
def deleteSelf(row):
    row.Brother = np.delete(row.Brother, np.where(row.Brother == row.Name))
    return(row)
df.apply(deleteSelf, axis = 1)

#              Name         Father          Brother
# 0      John Smith     Erick Moon  [Mathew Common]
# 1 Rodolph Ruppert   Ralph Docker               []
# 2   Mathew Common     Erick Moon     [John Smith]
# 3  Patrick French Stewart Adborn               []
```

Comment: It works great! I think of a very adequate solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
def same_father(me, data):
    hasdad = data.Father == data.at[me, 'Father']
    notme = data.index != me
    isbro = hasdad & notme
    return data.loc[isbro].index.tolist()

df2 = df.set_index('Name')
getbro = lambda x: same_father(x.name, df2)
df2['Brother'] = df2.apply(getbro, axis=1)
```

I think this should work.(untested)